# Using webpack only to copy images

Tags: webpack

Am I able to use webpack only to copy image files (and maybe optimize them) ?
Here Is my config file:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

let plugins = [
    new webpack.ProgressPlugin(),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns: [
            {from: './assets/img', to: './public/img'},
        ]
    }),
];

module.exports = (argv, env) => {
    plugins = [
        ...plugins,
    ];
    return {
        plugins: plugins,
    };
};
```

I'm getting error: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in 'C:\strony\www\polskieszlaki_new\strony'`

Comment: This is not the usage & purpose of Webpack, you can find much simpler tools to make this copy

Comment: I know that... but I prefer to have as few tools as possible.

Comment: Better to use nodejs for this if you've already insisted on the tool ;)